# problems getting values from query string

Tags: php, query-string

My below function that is copied from another function that works fine. Should get values from the query string and turn them into a date:

```
function updateShift()
    {
        echo $name = $_GET['shift_name'];

        echo $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$_GET['start_hours']}:{$_GET['start_minutes']} {$_GET['start_ampm']}"));
        echo $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$_GET['stop_hours']}:{$_GET['stop_minutes']} {$_GET['stop_ampm']}"));
}
```

However it returns:

```
Shift Name
1969-12-31 17:00:00
1969-12-31 17:00:00
```

Any idea why this works fine elsewhere but not here? The query string is there as evidenced by the shift_name coming through correctly.

Comment: What is the URI you requested?

Comment: action=update&shift=19&shift_name=Fun!&start_hours=4&start_minutes=0&start_ampm=PM&stop_hours=6&stop_minutes=0&stop_ampm=PM

Comment: Are you sure updateShift is executed, and not another function? I sometimes have this problem. Also, what if you remove '$name = ', '$start_date = ', and '$stop_date = '?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates you received were the start of the Unix epoch since your date function call was getting false (or 0) as the second argument.  I just ran some quick tests using your code and I am seeing that strtotime is returning false with the values supplied.

```
echo "{$_GET['start_hours']}:{$_GET['start_minutes']} {$_GET['start_ampm']}";
=> '4:0 PM'
```

You need to make sure you have 2 digits in your minutes field to allow strtotime to see it as a valid time and to parse it correctly.  To to this you can either update your query string, use [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) or sprintf to ensure you have the 2 digits required for the time to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do this:

```
function updateShift()
    {
        echo $name = $_GET['shift_name'];

        echo $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['start_hours'].':'.$_GET['start_minutes'].' '.$_GET['start_ampm']));
        echo $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['stop_hours'].':'.$_GET['stop_minutes'].' '.$_GET['stop_ampm']));
}
```

or

```
function updateShift()
    {
        echo $_GET['shift_name'];

        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['start_hours'].':'.$_GET['start_minutes'].' '.$_GET['start_ampm']));
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['stop_hours'].':'.$_GET['stop_minutes'].' '.$_GET['stop_ampm']));
}
```